# How to reduce time for taken by stored Procedure for inserting a single record?

Tags: sql-server

We wrote a stored procedure for selecting a  single record from DB at a time. Using the same stored procedure to read 2000 records it takes 4 seconds. Is there any way to optimize it? (like single stored procedure for 2000 records)

Here is my Stored procedure:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetItemValue](@ItemName VARCHAR(200),@TimeStamp as DATETIME)

AS

select * from EIItemData

where ItemName=@ItemName AND TimeStamp=@TimeStamp
```

Can anyone tell me how can this stored procedure can be optimized to read 2000 records instead of calling once for each item.

Comment: Show us what the first 5 of your 2000 calls look like and we can help you better with that.

Comment: Post the stored procedure - sounds like OO thinking in an SET based world...

Answer (score 1):

**SQL Query Analyzer**

http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3418031/Query-Analyzer-Tips-and-Tricks.htm

**Stored Procedure Optimization**

http://www.mssqlcity.com/Tips/stored_procedures_optimization.htm

**How-to-Optimize-Queries**

http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/2175621/How-to-Optimize-Queries-Theory-an-Practice.htm

last but not least Index, Index, Index...

Answer (score 0):

Consider that SQL Server (and all RDBMS) work best with set-based operations.

Consider changing your calling code (the client) to expect a set of records to read.

Please post your stored procedure, either reading or inserting, so we can help find the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your SQL, I'd say, hit up the following points:

1. Do not use `select *` syntax, just bring back columns you need.
2. I am guessing you do not have an index on the columns in the `where` clause.  Think about adding them.
3. If you need 2000 items, why not just bring them in one shot.